# jQuery selector to access ASP.NET Checkboxes that are selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox

I am looking for a little help building out the correct selector in jQuery. My application uses ASP.NET so I have to deal with client ID's that are rendered dynamically. Therefore I need to select elements based on assigned class name. The problem with this is that I am using the ASP.NET Checkbox control which wraps a `<span>` tag the Checkbox control. I currently am able to select the Checkbox I want using `input:first-child`...

Here is the rendered Checkbox

```
<span class="CheckboxClassName">
  <input id="xxxxx" type="checkbox" name="xxxxx" checked="checked" />
</span>
```

Here is the jQuery selector

```
$(".CheckboxClassName input:first-child")
```

This selection works by selecting the first child element of the  element, which is the Checkbox I want. The problem is I want to modify the selector to select only those Checkboxes that are "Checked". I was trying to use this ...

```
$(".CheckboxClassName input:first-child:checked")
```

but it is not working.

Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong and how to select ASP.NET Checkboxes that are selected?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try

```
$("span.CheckboxClassName input:checked");
```

I don't think that you need the `:first` selector really, unless there is a chance that you have more than one input as a descendent of a span with the CSS class `CheckboxClassName`.

Here's **[an example that you can play with](http://jsfiddle.net/russcam/NKn7x/)**.

Answer (score 3):

I've always had good luck with:

```
if($('.CheckboxClassName input').is(':checked')){

}
```